# Multilabel with binary classification in Keras

Tags: python, keras, neural-network, multilabel-classification

At this moment, i working with image classification using Keras, sci-kit learn, etc.

I will try to explain all the problem.
Like i said before, it's an image classification with multilabel.
My dataframe contain 4000 microscopic oil samples, and the labels, represent some particles in the current sample. I will give one example below.

Well, all the images in dataframe are labeled. Imagine that, each image contain one array with 13 values, already in binary, and of course, 1 for positive and 0 for negative.

e.g.

```
[0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

That means for each image, it's possible to have multiple outputs, in this case, the objective is to give one oil sample to CNN, and that can be return what particles are present in image.

I don't know if it's clearly enough, sorry for that, now i will explain my real problem.

In my CNN, i already set the output layer to 13 (following the number of labels in each image).
I don't know why, but when i train the model, the predicted Y return only one value, example:

```
Y predicted (sample 14): 3
Y predicted (sample 65): 11
```

I need to get the predctions with multi outputs, like:

```
Y predicted (sample 14): 3, 7, 9, 12
Y predicted (sample 65): 5, 8, 9, 11
```

I need help to solve this problem, because i stuck a long time trying. I appreciate if someone knows a strategy for this.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you provide the model summary please ?

Comment: @Pusheen_the_dev   Yes  https://pastebin.com/raw/nJputnuE    sorry if is a little messed, i just testing some Convs and MaxPooling. But even with the changes, I did not get the expected result, I'm a little lost

Comment: Thanks. What are you using as loss ? And how are you making your predictions ?

Comment: Using binary crossentropy...  For predictions i using "predict_classes", i already use only predict too.

Comment: The error is the use of "predict_classes", if I remember well, it returns the index where the highest value occured.
You should use "predict".
And you should change your loss to mae or mse

Comment: @Pusheen_the_dev I will make some tests. You know tell me why i cant use confusion matrix or F1? Both return error:  "ValueError: Classification metrics can't handle a mix of multilabel-indicator and continuous-multioutput targets
"

Comment: Please include any code in the question itself.

Comment: It's because they're not metrics suited for your problem.
Since your doing a regression here, not a classification.

Btw, are you expecting value like : [43,0,32,65,87]
Or value like : [0,1,1,0,1] ?
If second, you could add a sigmoid activation layer at the end of your model.

Comment: @Pusheen_the_dev Multi-label classification is still classification, not a regression problem.

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro : It's the same thing in fact. Multi label classification, or multi target regression. Only thing who change is if you want to get numerical or categorical output.
But I was saying this because if I remember well, the sklearn function do not take multi-target output for the confusion matrix method. Same for F1 score.
Sorry for the misunderstanding.

Comment: @Pusheen_the_dev i expecting value like: [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, ...] or current position, like: [3, 5].  I want this because it's to predict what's the problem in current sample.

Comment: @Pusheen_the_dev No, its misleading to say they are the same thing. Classification and regression are not the same.

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro Well, just check here : https://towardsdatascience.com/regression-models-with-multiple-target-variables-8baa75aacd For me, it is just nomenclature. When you are doing classification, you are doing a regression in fact. And what I said is still true concerning the metrics to use

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is called multi-label classification. It means more than one class in the output of the model can be present at a time, not just one.

Given a vector of predictions, you can obtain individual classes by applying thresholding:

```
thresh = 0.5
p = model.predict(some_input)
classes = []
for prob, idx in enumerate(p):
    if prob > thresh:
        classes.append(idx)

print(classes)
```

After executing this you will get a variable sized vector with different classes, as predicted by the model. The threshold (thresh) is a parameter you have to tune using a performance metric for binary classification applied to each class. You can also have different thresholds for each class.

The threshold is something you have to tune. Now you will get a vector of 0s and 1s, where 0 in

Comment: I think thats work. Making some tests, i get for example, Y pred: https://pastebin.com/raw/kDy12pvv
It's possible to transform that ouput to 0's or 1's? i set the threshold for 0.5

Comment: @AlexColombari For that just do some_list.append(int(prob > thresh))

Comment: thanks for help. Another question, i trying to apply compute_class_weight in my project, but no success because multi-label classification. I find some answers using i.e. Dict, but doesn't run in my problem. Do you know any strategy for my case? Thanks!